# Partial view jQuery script is not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

This *partial* view:

```
@model SetIsApprovedModel

    <form id="frmApprove" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-url="@(Url.Action("SetApprove", "AccountAdmin"))"
          data-ajax-success="onsuccess" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#approvePartial" data-ajax-loading="#loadingApprove"
          data-ajax-failure="failed">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.UserName" />
        <div class="row px-3 mb-1">
            <div class="col-md-5 text-md-end fw-bold">Approved: </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-start" id="IsApprovedDiv">
                <input id="chkApprove" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.IsApproved" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('change', "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
                /* $("#chkApprove").on('change', function (evt) { */
                $('#frmApprove').trigger('submit');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The script is not working. How can I correct it?
Note: if I click the submit button, it works, but I want this form is posted in response to a change event from the checkbox.

Comment: _"The script is not working" You should really elaborate on this. It is vague and doesn't clearly explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the script written in the partial view won't work after the partial view is rendered in a main view, because it's a .cshtml file. So I have a test which moves the script into the main view surrounded by `@section Scripts{}` and you can see my test result.

[image]

Or you can include the jQuery library in your partial view as well. For example, if you have a default ASP.NET Core project, you can write `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your script.

[image]

Comment: I use @section script{} in the main view, together with event delegation and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad to see your code working well : )

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76152773/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance. Also, the animation could benefit from a picture caption.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the handler to the checkbox, as you seem to have tried. Also, you can use the jQuery `submit` method.

```
$("#chkApprove").on('change', function (evt) {
  $('#frmApprove').submit();
});
```